# Build recommendation based on Store history not rating

Tags: recommender-system

I am working on recommendation engine which will suggest product/ SKU based on Store purchase history from distributor. I would like to to predict which products their existing stores will use in the next month based on their past behavior and that of similar customers. I do not have any rating as this data belong to small retailers/ pharmacy/ General store. I take 6 months purchase history of store and what products it bought.

Can anyone suggest what would be the best approach.

Comment: How will you predict what items customers will buy next month? With 6 months of data? Is there some strong periodicity in the data which allows you to say that if they bought A this month then they will likely buy B next month?

Comment: We have got 6 months of data history which can maximum go up to 1 year. I would like to recommend based on particular store history. For example, if store has taken products A, B, C, D, E in last 6 months from distributor. What would be the list of product it can buy next month. Should i go ahead with probability model instead of collabrative/ content based filtering or popularity model.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you edit your question with a specific example? what, how?